# Flutter The return type 'Map<int, int>' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i want to return a map from a FirebaseDatabase. But i get the Error Code:

*The return type 'Map<int, int>' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context.*

if i print the map i get the right result. Im new in Flutter and i dont get it why its doesnt work. I guess i need to change the method type, but how?

````
  String u1= 'Backsquat';

  Dataread(String u1);

  DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;



  Map? read()  {
    Map <int,int> werte;

    data.child("Kraftwerte").child(auth.currentUser.uid).child(u1).onValue.listen((event) {
      werte = event.snapshot.value;
      print(werte);
      return werte;
    }); ```
````

Comment: I've not worked with Firebase, but that `listen` function looks like a stream interface, which is asynchronous. Every time a value is read, a callback is executed that gets passed the value. That callback is expected to return `void`. If you want to read a list of values, you likely need to `await` another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that your stream is asynchronous, while your actual function is synchronous.
If all you want is to return `event.snapshot.value` for every item on your stream, you can do this:

```
Stream<Map?> read() {
  return data.child("Kraftwerte").child(auth.currentUser.uid).child(u1).onValue.map<Map>((event) => event.snapshot.value);
}
```

If what you want is to get the first value of the stream:

```
Future<Map?> read() async {
  final event = await data.child("krafwerte").child(auth.currentUser.uid).child(u1).onValue.first;

  return event.snapshot.value as Map?;
}
```

Either way, your code **must** be async

### example of using the code:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget buuld(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _read(),
      builder: (context, snapshot)  {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text(snapshot.error!);
        if (snapshot.hasData) return Text(snapshot.data!['key']); // snapshot.data is the map, it's null if the future is not done.
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    );
  }

  Future<Map> _read() {
    final event = await data.child("krafwerte").child(auth.currentUser.uid).child(u1).onValue.first;

    return event.snapshot.value as Map?;
  }
}
```

To better understand how the future builder widget works, please [read the future builder docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: I thought IT works because i printed the resault and get somthing Back. But i have the Problem that i want to get the resault into a For Loop to Make Widgets Out of the map. But IT seems that i dont get a map Back its a Feature<Map<object,object>> or somthing Like this. Ist there a simply was to get a Map Out of the Stream/Future or Cast it to map and for Loop the Resault to get Widgets from it?  I read the flutter firebase doc but they Stop in the Point when they Make somthing with the recived data. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage. I have no Idea to solvee this

Comment: I have added an example of using the data using the `FutureBuilder` widget, you can also use the [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) widget for the stream example.

Comment: i think its to advanced for me. i get a  "Instance of '_MapStream<Event, Map<dynamic, dynamic>>"
i thought i get a Map<String,Int> back and i can use this map directly for making  widgets in a for loop.

perhaps i need a to work with models so i can get the data into the model and than i can create widgets out of the model.